# I have created a database named 'credentials' having 'userinfo' table in it on wamp server. I am not able to connect the database through php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection, wampserver

Error:
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\form\update.php on line 8

PHP code:

```
<?php

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$dbName = 'credentials';

$link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
if (!$link) {

    die("Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$connect = "INSERT INTO userinfo (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
if (mysqli_query($link, $connect)) {

    echo "New record created successfully";
}else {

    echo "Error: " . $connect . "<br>" . mysql_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Check if you have a User created to access the Database and you are using that username and password details in the DB connection settings in your code

Answer (score 0):

Need to grant permissions to the user@host in mysql. The grant command looks like

```
grant all privileges on YOURDB.* to 'YOURUSER'@'localhost' identified by 'YOURPASSWORD';
```

Comment: how am i suppose to do that?

Comment: You'll need to log into the database interface as the root/admin user to do this. For example, using phpmyadmin or the mysql command line client.

Answer (score 0):

The value of variables:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
```

Must be the REAL login information of your database server, something like 'root' or another user, and the password defined during the server setup.